# How to display frames that are separated from an animated GIF?

Tags: php, animated-gif

I'm trying to use [GifFrameExractor](https://github.com/Sybio/GifFrameExtractor).  Full code for it is at the link if needed, but I dont think you will for the purposes of this question.

My code on my site is the following, using an animated gif of Homer Simpson...

```
$gifFilePath = 'images/homer.gif';

if (GifFrameExtractor::isAnimatedGif($gifFilePath)) { // check this is an animated GIF

    $gfe = new GifFrameExtractor();

    $gfe->extract($gifFilePath);

    // Do something with extracted frames ...
    foreach ($gfe->getFrames() as $frame) {

        // The frame resource image var
        $img = $frame['image'];
        echo $img;

        // The frame duration
        $duration = $frame['duration'];

    }

}
```

But my addition of "echo $img;" just outputs a bunch of resource IDs like "Resource id #8Resource id #10Resource id #12" and so on.

I googled and it says resource ID means you're trying to output a resource but you first need to extract info from the resource.

So how do I extract the actual img info so that I can display each frame from the animated gif?

I basically just want to display each of the frames of the animated gif down the page.

Any ideas?

Comment: they appear to be just gd handles, so `imagejpeg($frame['image'])`?

Comment: I added $source =  imagejpeg($frame['image']); echo "<img src='$source'>"; and that just displays a bunch of weird icons "����JFIF��>CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v62), default quality ��" etc.  Obviously im doing something very wrong haha

Comment: yep. that's raw jpeg binary data. you'd need a `header('Content-type: image/jpeg')` to tell your browser that it IS an image

Comment: Thank you, that displays the first image in the GIF now, with the header added. Any idea how I would get ALL frames from the GIF to display down the page?  Do I have to create all images and save them to my site's folder first (and then read them)?  Or can it be done on the fly?

Comment: you could use data uris, but but that'd make for a very "heavy" page since you'd have base64 copies of each image embedded in the html.

Comment: Ok, in that case I'll probably save them to my site to a temp folder and just automatically delete them after a certain amount of time.  Thanks for your insight!